# Node Rest API with static Key Authentication

Tags: api, rest, express, passport.js

I wanted to allow my APIs to be access through a single key only. This API key will be in my environment variable file. Every time user will try to access my API. I'll first check whether key 
present in the request body or not. After that I will check key matching with my fixed key. If both the condition will get satisfied I'll call api otherwise will response with 401 error.

I tried looking for middleware but not found any solution for this situation. Passport can be used 
but it is asking for username and password for basic/local/digest strategy, Oauth and OpenId are based on third party provider.

I solved this by adding key check functionality in my controller itself.Like router directly route to 
my API and after getting into the API controller I am call key authentication function. But it seems not to be standard way. 
Instead I wanted to stop user at route lever itself.

Please share appropriate solution if anyone come across such situation.

Comment: You don't need, and shouldn't have more authentication over checking the API key against the static key. It seems like you want to track by which user the API calls are coming from, and in that case you should create a unique API key for each user. Don't make it more complicated than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just need to check the key it should be super easy to do in a route middleware, eg:

```
var checkApiKey = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.body.apiKey !== process.env.API_KEY) {
    return res.status(401).json({status: 'error'});
  }
  next();
};

app.all('/api/*', checkApiKey);

app.get('/api/something', function(req, res) {
  return res.json({status: 'ok', message: 'You knew the key! Congrats!'});
});
```